# Is there anyway I can download the file in Google colaboratory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying tensorflow in Google Colaboratory from this codelab, 
I need to download 'http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz' this file to complete the lab.

How I can download the file. Is there anyway to upload the tar file without downloading it on my machine.

I tried this method

```
import urllib
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

This doesn't work, wget is not found also. Anyone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: try `import urllib.request` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read the manual, they have good examples and explanations: [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

To download:

```
>>> import os
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 'google.png')
('google.png', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x7fba3c4cb908>)
>>> os.listdir()
['google.png']
```

To just check the content:

```
>>> with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
...     print(f.read(300))
```

Answer (score 68):

Possibly simpler: use `!wget`, e.g., executing a cell with the command:

```
!wget https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

will save the file to the local filesystem of the VM. (Note the leading `!`. This is a signal to execute the line as a shell command.)

Comment: you can also set the `%%bash` magic on top to use multiple bash commands in one cell

Comment: You can use wget's -O flag to specify where you want to save the downloaded file, like this: `wget -O mydir/output-file.png https://example.com/image.png`